# Microsoft Storage Spaces as MAC OS X time machine destination

Tags: windows-10, time-machine, storage-spaces

I have several MacBooks at home. And I want to build home backup solution based on Microsoft's Storage Spaces ( Windows 10 Pro). It would utilize ReFS and "three way mirror". I guess, it is hardware agnostic and reliable configuration. The question is: Would "Time Machine" work with shared folder which is placed in "Storage Space"?

Answer (score 0):

Not reliably. Officially, Time Machine only supports backing up to local volumes in Mac OS Extended (aka HFS+ and HFSX) format, Mac computers running OS X Server's Time Machine service, and Apple's Time Capsule appliance. It's possible to get Time Machine to back up to unsupported network servers, but it's not recommended; it really wants some special sauce on the server side to avoid problems (i.e. corrupt backups) if the client disconnects partway through a backup.

So, you'd wind up with a reliable storage solution hosting self-corrupting backups. Not very useful.